# Extend call (extnd-call) fails with EC500 config

Tags: avaya

I have configure `EC500` on my Avaya system, and created an `extnd-call` button on my phone.  When I am in a call, and I hit the `Extend Call` button, my phone beeps and the `EC500` configured mobile phone does not ring.

What does this mean?

Comment: Have you looked in your Avaya manual? Most commercial phone system manuals have an extensive section devoted to error codes like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had `Exclusion` enabled by default on all `stations`.  So `extend call` will only dial the `EC500` when `exclusion` is disabled on a per-station basis (a user can do this manually on their `station`).